# Could not load file or assembly in asmx on server

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have a webservice created in c# and is serving the webpage. It works fine locally on system. When I moved it to server I am getting the following error when webservice is called through ajax call.

```
"{"Message":"Could not load file or assembly \u0027MySql.Data, Version=6.6.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=\u0027 or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.","StackTrace":"   at filename.webserviehello()","ExceptionType":"System.IO.FileNotFoundException"}"
```

What i am missing here?

I am using MySql for db.

Comment: mysqlconnector is not installed on server and you have not uploaded mysql.data dll on server

Comment: i have published the project so i guess it would have gone to server...is it?

Comment: You need to make sure by checking bin folder of publish

Comment: give me 2 min...i will upload

Comment: bin folder is already there...still same issue

Comment: You have to check in bin folder that mysql.data dll exists or not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73263/discussion-between-ghost-and-ehsan-sajjad).